# binary containing just one instruction

Tags: gcc, embedded, cross-compiling

I want to produce a binary file to load to mips target (barebone/no os) that will contain only one jump instruction and will be linked to the specific address. How to do it? With all my attempts, I get quite big files, that apparently contain linked libraries (they are unnecessary for one single jump instruction). I believe I shall get a file of just few bytes in length. How to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what your toolset is, but if you have GNU binutils, there's probably some invocation of `objcopy` that will do what you need.

Comment: Without seeing your code and command lines, we cannot help you really. Please [edit] your question and provide them.